# What is the meaning of conda's build string?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

If I run `conda info sphinx` from the command line, the last entry as of August 24, 2017, is

```
sphinx 1.6.3 py36_0
-------------------
file name   : sphinx-1.6.3-py36_0.tar.bz2
name        : sphinx
version     : 1.6.3
build string: py36_0
...
```

What is the meaning of the  build string, which is mirrored above in the package version? Is this the minimum version of the python interpereter required by a package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first part of the build string (`pyXX`) of this package tells you the exact version of the Python interpreter that this package can be used for. Most likely, there are other packages for other versions of Python (`py27`, `py35`, etc.). The second part (after the underscore) tells you the build number of this package. The build number is typically incremented when there is a change in the build recipe, but no change in the version of the software being built. You can find more information in [the description of the `info/index.json` fields](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/package-spec.html#info-index-json).

Note, however, that [the build string will be changing with conda build 3.0](https://www.anaconda.com/package-better-conda-build-3/).

Package maintainers can customize their build strings using `meta.yml` (see [Conda Build Documentation on Build section](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#build-section)).