# Why does my anaconda *.yml file reference two different versions of python?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to understand how to read the anaconda *.yml files better, and couldn't find much documentation online:

name: AdvML

channels:

- defaults

dependencies:

- jupyter=1.0.0=py36_3
- numpy=1.13.1=py36_0
- pip=9.0.1=py36_1
- python=3.6.2=0
- scikit-learn=0.19.0=np113py36_0
- matplotlib=2.0.2=np113py36_0
- pip:

  - tensorflow==1.3.0

So I have two questions:

1. What does - jupyter=1.0.0=py36_3 mean? I assumed it means that the dependency is jupyter version 1.0.0, but what does =py36_3 mean? And why does the following line have =py36_0? I don't understand why particular package versions are being referenced to particular python versions, and why different python versions are being referenced.
2. Why is there a pip heading? If I activated an anaconda environment and then used pip to install a package (eg tensorflow in this case), why isn't tensorflow just part of the regular dependency list, rather than a separate pip list?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first question is answered in: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45874816/2449192 (disclaimer, that's my answer). Please only ask one question per post... the answer to your second question is because that's how the conda maintainers decided to do it. Since conda install and pip install are separate operations, and not all packages are available via both commands, it make sense to separate them.

Comment: Didn't notice that thread, thanks!