# What does the number after python package version mean in environment.yml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

```
dependencies:
  - ca-certificates=2019.1.23=0
  - certifi=2019.3.9=py36_0
  - click=7.0=py36_0
  - flask=1.0.2=py36_1
  - itsdangerous=1.1.0=py36_0
  - jinja2=2.10=py36_0
  - libedit=3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
  - ffmpeg=3.4=h7985aa0_0
```

The above .yml file is generated from `conda env export`

What does the number `py36_0` and `hc058e9b_0` mean?

I imagine the first type is python 3.6.0 version?

What about the second type?

Comment: This is data represented in YAML form, which has nothing to do with YAML per sé, just like it has nothing to do with ASCII (or UTF-8), although it uses that character set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of conda's build string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874816/what-is-the-meaning-of-condas-build-string) Also note that the hash-based build strings (`hc058e9b`) are for non-Python libraries, but still follow the `<build string>_<build number>` format.

Comment: @merv Python packages can still have the hash type of build string, primarily if they have C-extensions. See, e.g., the NumPy package: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/numpy/files